# How can an item be added to a ListBox a specific number of times?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want to add items to ListBox a specific number of times based on input. For example, if I input 5, it should add say, "DOG" 5 times to the ListBox. My code so far:

```
Dim number As Integer
number = TextBox1.Text
Dim add As String
add = POS.DescriptionText.Text
While number = add
   POS.ListBox1.Items.Add(number)
End While
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Is Yahoo Answers not working this week?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Dim text = "DOG" // maybe POS.DescriptionText.Text according to your code
For X As Integer = 1 To Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    POS.ListBox1.Items.Add(text)
Next
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR ITS NOW WORKING GOOD